# Writing and reading bitmap from stream in android

Tags: android, bitmap, stream

I am trying to send and read bitmap via bluetooth in two android phones and I have used the following code to achieve it.

```
public void writeBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
     socketOutputStream.write(BitmapUtils.toByteArray(bitmap));
     socketOutputStream.flush();
}
public Bitmap readBitmap(final int BITMAP_SIZE) throws IOException {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(socketInputStream);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            Log.i("Bitmap", "Error In receiving bitmap");
        }
        else{
            Log.i("BitmapSize","Size: "+bitmap.getByteCount());
        }
        return bitmap;

    }
```

The above code works well, but it takes a lot of time to write and read . I know the problem is when I convert bitmap to byteArray it takes up an incredible space in comparison to the original bitmap size. Could anyone tell me the correct method to write and read bitmap over socket .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your gonna probably want to instead, resize the bitmap instead of handle the original bitmap. There is no garuntee you will be able to parse a large bitmap image. There is a relevant post here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html You can do this both reading and writing, of course you will have to edit the code a bit.

Comment: @inner_class7 wont that reduce the quality of the image? I want the original image to be sent over bluetooth.

Comment: It should not reduce the quality of the image, unless the original image bounds are smaller then the display size. For example, if your original image is 1280x960 and a device your using has 320 PPI your image should be no larger than 4 x 3 inches in a display area. Otherwise the quality will be reduced. However, if you reduce the image down using the same PPI you will lose no resolution only image size. Compared to if you upscale to 5 x 4 with the same resolution on 320 PPI you will lose clarity because the image will cover more pixels than the image contains.